# SQL Join with 2 conditions same column but different data names

Tags: sql-server

I need to join 2 tables using 2 columns as identifiers,

Reference and UAP

```
TABLE 1

Reference
UAP
Week 1
Week 2

Table 2
Reference
UAP
Stock
```

Here is the problem with data on both tables in UAP column

```
Table 1    Table 2
UAP1       M1
UAP2       M2
UAP3       M3
UAP4       M4
UAP5       M5
UAP6       M6
UAPP       PROTOS
EXT        EXTR
```

- the UAPS are the same but name is just different
- I have no control over the data i'm getting, it's a IBM DB2 remote server
- I tried a local table to join but i want to avoid that 'cause of the performance impact (30+ seconds)

So far my query is this

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT 
        P.Referencia, 
        P.UAP, 
        P.W01, 
        P.W02,
        S.Stock
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.Production AS P
    INNER JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.Stock S
    ON S.Reference = S.Reference
    WHERE (P.Reference Not Like ''FS%'')
    ORDER BY Reference')
```

well of course the ideal would be

```
 SELECT 
        *
    FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
        'SELECT 
            P.Referencia, 
            P.UAP, 
            P.W01, 
            P.W02,
            S.Stock
        FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.Production AS P
        INNER JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.Stock S
        ON P.Reference = S.Reference AND P.UAP = S.UAP
        WHERE (P.Reference Not Like ''FS%'')
        ORDER BY Reference')
```

but it does not work cause different names... Is there a way to make this happen without a local join table that will slow my query by several seconds?

Here is the output of these queries individually

This is the production table

[image: This is Production table]

This is the stock table

[image: Stock Table]

the output should show me the Stock on the production table by Reference and UAP

**EDIT**

Sorry for confusion the remote server is IBM DB2. This was an error of my coworker that said it was coming from oracle--

Cheers for correct answer from @Sergey Menshov.

```
SELECT
    Reference,  
    UAP, 
    W01, 
    W02
FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT 
        P.Reference, 
        P.UAP, 
        P.W01, 
        P.W02
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.Production AS P
    LEFT JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.Stock S
    ON P.Reference = S.Reference AND
         S.UAP =
             CASE P.UAP
                  WHEN ''UAP1'' THEN ''M1''
                  WHEN ''UAP2'' THEN ''M2''
                  WHEN ''UAP3'' THEN ''M3''
                  WHEN ''UAP4'' THEN ''M4''
                  WHEN ''UAP5'' THEN ''M5''
                  WHEN ''UAP6'' THEN ''M6''
                  WHEN ''UAPP'' THEN ''PROTOS''
                  WHEN ''EXT'' THEN ''EXTR''
                END
        WHERE (P.Reference Not Like ''FS%'')
    ORDER BY Reference DESC')
```

another method which gives error in UAP1 not a column in table L that might work using dual table for DB2

```
    SELECT
    Reference,  
    UAP, 
    W01, 
    W02
FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT 
        P.Reference, 
        P.UAP, 
        P.W01, 
        P.W02
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.Production AS P
    JOIN 
        (
            SELECT ''UAP1'' AS UAP1, ''M1'' AS UAP2 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
            UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP2'',''M2'' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
            UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP3'',''M3'' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
            UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP4'',''M4'' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
            UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP5'',''M5'' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
            UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP6'',''M6'' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
            UNION ALL SELECT ''UAPP'',''PROTOS'' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
            UNION ALL SELECT ''EXT'',''EXTR'' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
        ) L
        ON P.UAP = L.UAP1
        INNER JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.Stock S
        ON P.Reference = S.Reference AND S.UAP = L.UAP2
        WHERE (P.Reference Not Like ''FS%'')
    ORDER BY Reference DESC')
```

Comment: Can you give an example with an input sample and expected output?

Comment: I updated the main post with images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a link-subquery:

```
FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.Production AS P
JOIN
  (
    SELECT ''UAP1'' AS UAP1,''M1'' AS UAP2 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP2'',''M2'' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP3'',''M3'' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP4'',''M4'' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP5'',''M5'' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP6'',''M6'' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT ''UAPP'',''PROTOS'' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT ''EXT'',''EXTR'' FROM DUAL
  ) L
ON P.UAP=L.UAP1 -- !!!
INNER JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.Stock S
ON P.Reference = S.Reference AND S.UAP=L.UAP2 -- !!!
```

Or you can create a link-table in the Oracle and then use it in your query.
I think it'll be better because you can use it in other queries and insert there a new combinations.

Pseudo code:

```
CREATE TABLE UAP_LINK(
  UAP1 VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  UAP2 VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(UAP1),
UNIQUE(UAP2)
)

INSERT UAP_LINK VALUES
UAP1, M1
UAP2, M2
UAP3, M3
UAP4, M4
UAP5, M5
UAP6, M6
UAPP, PROTOS
EXT , EXTR
```

One more variant with `CASE`:

```
FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.Production AS P
INNER JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.Stock S
ON P.Reference = S.Reference
  AND S.UAP=
        CASE P.UAP
          WHEN ''UAP1'' THEN ''M1''
          WHEN ''UAP2'' THEN ''M2''
          WHEN ''UAP3'' THEN ''M3''
          WHEN ''UAP4'' THEN ''M4''
          WHEN ''UAP5'' THEN ''M5''
          WHEN ''UAP6'' THEN ''M6''
          WHEN ''UAPP'' THEN ''PROTOS''
          WHEN ''EXT'' THEN ''EXTR''
        END
```

Comment: this gives me an error DUAL in (username) type *FILE not found.

Comment: Is it Oracle or another linked DB?

Comment: Try to remove all `FROM DUAL` from subquery `SELECT ''UAP1'' UAP1,''M1'' UAP2
UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP2'',''M2''
UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP3'',''M3''
UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP4'',''M4''
UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP5'',''M5''
UNION ALL SELECT ''UAP6'',''M6''
UNION ALL SELECT ''UAPP'',''PROTOS''
UNION ALL SELECT ''EXT'',''EXTR''`.

Comment: Sorry the provider is actualy IBM DB2, i had to ask another coworker about this...

Comment: Try to replace `FROM DUAL` into `FROM sysibm.sysdummy1`. https://lstierneyltd.com/blog/development/tips/db2s-equivalent-of-oracles-dual/

Comment: this worked but now says column UAP1 does not exist in table L

Comment: I've added one more variant with `CASE` into my answer.

Comment: I'm glad. )) Also try to add `AS` into the subquery `SELECT ''UAP1'' AS UAP1,''M1'' AS UAP2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`. I've never used DB2 but maybe it'll help. About `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysdummy1table.html

Comment: I tried adding AS but still didn't work, would like to know how to work with this method tho, still trying to figure out. I'll edit topic with these queries

Comment: I edited main post and added how the query currently looks like on my side

Comment: Try to change into `INNER JOIN 
        (...
        ) AS L
        ON P.UAP = L.UAP1`. I don't know but maybe it'll help. :)

Comment: One more idea - try to use the following `INNER JOIN (VALUES(''UAP1'',''M1''),(''UAP2'',''M2''),(''UAP3'',''M3''),(''UAP4'',''M4''),(''UAP5'',''M5''),(''UAP6'',''M6''),(''UAPP'',''PROTOS''),(''EXT'',''EXTR'')) AS L(UAP1,UAP2) ON P.UAP = L.UAP1` instead of that subquery with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: This gives me Error type 6 has occurred. Error types and their meanings are: 1 -- Arithmetic overflow. 2 -- Floating point overflow.

Comment: Ok, I give up. DB2 syntax is very strange and I don't know why it is not working there. :) I'm glad that a variant with `CASE` is working for you. Good luck! :)